# What's the easiest way to trim an MP4 video on Windows 8, without re-encoding?

Tags: video, mp4

I have an MP4 file which I'd like to split in two, without re-encoding the audio or video.

I'm happy to split at a keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MKVmerge for that specific task. All you need to do is install the program from [here](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MKVtoolnix) and then input the video and specify where you want the split in the **Global** tab. The output is in .mkv but it doesn't encode video/audio. You can split at specific time-code/duration, size, not through video frames, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFmpeg for this, using `-ss` to determine the output start point, and `-t` to determine *how long* the output will last for. To split a 15 minute file into three five-minute sections:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 00:05:00 output1.mp4 \
-c copy -ss 00:05:00 -t 00:05:00 output2.mp4 \
-c copy -ss 00:10:00 -t 00:05:00 output3.mp4
```